# Return a new instance of javax.inject.Provider using lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have a code segment:

```
private static <T> Provider<T> getProviderInstance(T value) {
    return new Provider<T>() {
        @Override
        public T get() {
            return value;
        }

    };
}
```

I want to refactor it using lambda. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose if `Provider` is Functional interface with abstract `get()` method like below

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Provider<T>{
    abstract T get();
 }
```

Then the corresponding lambda expression is

```
Provider<String> p = ()->"hello";
System.out.println(p.get());       //hello
```